# Print correlation data in same plot position across facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a faceted `ggplot2` scatterplot, and would like to print summary statistics about the linear regression on each facet, as has been done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15470508/741348) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022553/adding-r2-on-graph-with-facets). Unlike those examples, I am using `scales="free"`, and the ranges of the data in each facet are quite different, but I would like the summary statistics to show up in the same relative position in each facet (e.g. top right corner, or whatever). How can I specify to `geom_text` or `annotate` that the label should appear in the same position relative to the panel?

Where I am right now:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(2112)
x <- c(1:10, 6:15)
y <- x + c(runif(10), runif(10)*10)
l <- gl(2, 10)
d <- data.frame(x=x, y=y, l=l)

# Calculate a summary statistic (here, the r-squared) in a separate data frame
r_df <- ddply(d, .(l), summarise, rsq=round(summary(lm(y~x))$r.squared, 2))

# Use geom_text and a separate data frame to print the summary statistic
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_text(data=r_df, aes(x=8, y=8, label=paste("rsq=", rsq)))+
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~l, scales="free")
```

[image]

I would like, instead, to have `ggplot` automatically position the text in the same relative position in each facet.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to place them relative to the corners, you can achieve that by specifying an `x` or `y` position of `Inf` or `-Inf`:

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_text(data=r_df, aes(label=paste("rsq=", rsq)), 
            x=-Inf, y=Inf, hjust=-0.2, vjust=1.2)+
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~l, scales="free")
```

[image]

I also adjusted `hjust` and `vjust` so the label was not in the exact corner of the graph by pushed away from it a bit.

Comment: I'm guessing a more general solution involves delving into grid graphics?

Comment: @DrewSteen Delving into grid would be needed for the more general solution because all specifications inside the plot area in ggplot are specified in data space and for the same relative position you want to specify them in display space.

Comment: You could also change the facet labels to include this information as seen in [the R Cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/#modifying-facet-label-text)

Comment: @DrewSteen where do you want them, that +/- Inf doesn't already cover?

Comment: @baptiste: Ideally, I'd like to be able to place them at any arbitrary position within the facet window (e.g., 32% of the way from left to right, 67% of the way from bottom to top, or whatever).

Comment: @DrewSteen `p + annotation_custom(grob=textGrob("hi", x=0.32, y=1-0.67))`

Comment: @baptiste I forgot about `annotation_custom` and its specification in terms of relative coordinates within the plot window.

Comment: i often wish I could forget about it, it's rather buggy

Comment: @baptiste Was just playing with it and could not figure out how to put a different annotation in each facet. Is that a functionality that it has?